# html5 validation form tag

Tags: html, forms, validation

"The for attribute of the label element must refer to a form control."

Honestly, I don't understand what's wrong with the markup. I've looked through so much of the W3's site and just can't get it.

Help?

HTML:

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
    <div>
        <label for="name">Name</label><br />
        <input type="text" value="" name="name" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="email">E-mail</label><br />
        <input type="text" value="" name="email" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="message">Message</label><br />
        <textarea name="message" cols="30" rows="4"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" value="yes" name="newsletter" />
        <label for="newsletter">Subscribe to newsletter</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="subscribe" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Just curious:  How did you know you had a problem?  Did your form fail to validate?

Comment: Yes sir! I always validate my pages... and am fine with hacks and weird things getting flagged.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're missing the `id` attribute.

So to fix it, for example:

```
<input type="text" value="" name="email" id="email" />
```

That's it. [Linky.](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fjsbin.com%2Falake4&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

Comment: went from 4 errors to 13. took out some of the elements to figure them out one by one. here's validation of just the "name" input. http://cl.ly/2L0Q15020N0723180h1V

Comment: You're supposed to put the `id` attributes on the `input`, not the `label`. See the example page I made which I linked to through the validator: http://jsbin.com/alake4/edit Also, you don't want to have the `value` attribute (or `type="text"`) on the `label` tag.

Comment: Current editor's draft says, "The for attribute may be specified to indicate a form control with which the caption is to be associated. If the attribute is specified, the attribute's value must be the ID of a labelable element in the same Document as the label element."  So @thirtydot is correct.

Answer (score 8):

Thirtydot is correct; there is amissing id in your form. I have added all.
Check this:

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
    <div>
        <label for="name">Name</label><br />
        <input type="text" id="name" value="" name="name" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="email">E-mail</label><br />
        <input type="text" id="email" value="" name="email" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="message">Message</label><br />
        <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="4"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="newsletter" value="yes" name="newsletter" />
        <label for="newsletter">Subscribe to newsletter</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="subscribe" />
    </div>
</form>
```